# Set Binding as other Binding's Source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `TabControl`, and I want to do the following:

1. Take first and last of the `TabItem`s in `TabControl.Items`
2. Get their `Margin`s
3. Supply those `Thickness`es to the converter to convert these two structs into final value

Here is a related code showing what I am trying to do:

```
<Border.Padding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarginsToPaddingConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Margin">
            <Binding.Source>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}" Path="Items" Converter="{StaticResource ItemCollectionToFirstItemConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Type TabItem}" />
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
        <Binding Path="Margin">
            <Binding.Source>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}" Path="Items" Converter="{StaticResource ItemCollectionToLastItemConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Type TabItem}" />
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </MultiBinding>
</Border.Padding>
```

But I can't set `Binding` as `RelativeSource` or `Source` of other `Binding`. Basically the solution at hand is to create converter, which would take `TabControl.Items` and convert it to the final value, but the problem is I want to animate `Margin`s of both `TabItem`s, so I need to bind specifically to these properties. If I would bind to `TabControl.Items`, the `Border.Padding` would not get refreshed if `Margin` of any `TabItem` would change. So what should I do?

### Update

Ok, so one of the possible solutions is to hook into `TabItem.Loaded` event, and then use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to hook `Changed` event on appropriate properties, then hook all items in `TabItem.Items` collection, hook any new items and automatically unhook all old items, and hook like million other stuff. But this is quite complicated and it's like 400 LOC. Isn't there anything simpler? Preferably in pure `XAML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this modified response is not as elegant as I'd like, but it should work.

Basically, use another dummy control as a relay for the binding. Specifically, this scenario arises when you want to pull the first and last of a collection. You can't just use a converter to grab the first/last and the property all at once, because if you change a property on the first or last item, the converter won't pick up the change. So you have to do something that melds in with dependency properties - almost like some sort of a second order dependency property would be nice.

Anyways, here's some code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CollectionHelper : Control
    {
        public static DependencyProperty CollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Collection",
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(CollectionHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCollectionChanged));

        public IEnumerable Collection
        {
            get { return GetValue(CollectionProperty) as IEnumerable; }
            set { SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnCollectionChanged(object rawSender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            CollectionHelper sender = (CollectionHelper)rawSender;
            IEnumerable value = args.NewValue as IEnumerable;
            if(value==null)
            {
                sender.First = null;
                sender.Last = null;
                return;
            }
            bool isFirstSet = false;
            object lastItemTemp = null;
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                if (!isFirstSet)
                {
                    sender.First = item;
                    isFirstSet = true;
                }
                lastItemTemp = item;
            }
            if (!isFirstSet)
                sender.First = null;
            sender.Last = lastItemTemp;
        }

        public DependencyProperty FirstProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "First",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(CollectionHelper));

        public object First
        {
            get { return GetValue(FirstProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FirstProperty, value); }
        }

        public DependencyProperty LastProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Last",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(CollectionHelper));

        public object Last
        {
            get { return GetValue(LastProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LastProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

And an actual use case:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Helper="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Helper:CollectionHelper x:Name="Helper" Collection="{Binding SomeStrings}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Helper, Path=First}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Helper, Path=Last}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So the idea here would be to grab the first and last item using the relay control and then bind to there margins.

Comment: You are setting `Path` property twice on a single `Binding` - I'm pretty sure this won't work.

Comment: You're right. See edited response. It's not elegant like I'd like, but it'll give you a reusable tool.

Comment: You mean like `<TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=Helper, Path=First.Margin}" />`? Won't this throw an exception when `Helper.First` is null?

Comment: That part is left as an exercise for the reader. ;) But in all seriousness, you have a variety of choices there. You could set a default return value in place of null, such as an empty Control or something that has a Margin, etc. You could even make that a dep. prop.!

Comment: Yeah using another control as a mediator is probably the only reusable solution. It's somewhat sad WPF does not have direct support for this. One could expect that. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. I think you'd still want more than one layer in there to make it very clear what's going on, but having a dummy control is a lame solution.